# Можно ли сказать "разговаривать кого-то"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование

Есть точно слово ***разговорить*** в смысле *заставить кого-то разговориться.* А можно ли так сказать в несовершенной форме (проблема в том, что слово тогда совпадает с основным значением, означающим *говорить*, например *разговаривать по телефону* или *разговаривать громко)?*

Comment: Будет сложно построить фразу так, чтобы из контекста было очевидно, что имеется в виду именно значение _"разговорить"_. А без этого фраза будет выглядеть совершенно неестественно.

Comment: Ну например: *Каждый раз я разговариваю Виталика с большим трудом". Понятно же?

Comment: Нет, непонятно, и выглядит очень неестественно. Глагол _"разговорить"_ в форме _"разговаривать"_ употребляется очень редко (если вообще). Я бы посоветовал написать эту фразу как _"Каждый раз мне удаётся разговорить Виталика с большим трудом"_. Можно подобрать и получше вариант, наверное, но в любом случае, тут сразу понятен смысл.

Comment: Спасибо, freim! Наверно, так и есть, то есть лучше перефразировать, например, как у Вас. Хорошо бы ещё кто-то высказался в подобном ключе и поставил точку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что говорится в МАС:
[**разговори́ть**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ozhegov-term-28713.htm), -рю, -ришь; *сов., перех.* (*несов.* [разгова́ривать(2)](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-90280.htm)).
**1.** *(**несов. нет**). Разг.* ["наш" смысл]
Заставить разговориться, вызвать желание вступить в разговор.
*{Олег} легко разговорил и без того словоохотливую и моложавую Варвару Дмитриевну*. Фадеев, Молодая гвардия.
**2.** *Разг.* Развлечь, рассеять беседой.
*— Вот сейчас подойду и заговорю с ним. Разговорю его, чтобы он отвлекся от своих мыслей.* Панова, Спутники.
**3.** *Разг. устар.*
Отговорить от чего-либо.
*Попытка разговорить пристанских не заводить смуты кончилась для него ничем.* Мамин-Сибиряк, Три конца.

Получается, что глагола несовершенного вида ***разговаривать*** — в том смысле, который Вы имеете в виду, — нет.
Но слово-то ведь разговорное. Теоретически, если Вы сообщаете о мужчине, которого вам трудно разговорить по каким-то причинам, и этот процесс его "разговаривания" всё усложняется ("Каждый раз я разговариваю Виталика с большим трудом"), то, думаю, Вас поймут.

В письменной же речи, конечно, надо использовать глагол совершенного вида: удалось разговорить, все сложнее разговорить, пытаюсь разговорить.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!